# overriding previously-bound click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

When I use this code with an element whose id is "foobar":

```
$("#foobar").click(function () { alert("first"); });
$("#foobar").click(function () { alert("second"); });
```

I get two alerts: "first" and "second" second.

How do I specify a click event that also clears out any previous click events attached to the element? I want the last `$("#foobar").click(...)` to erase any previously bound events.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can unbind the events already attached to that element, and then attach the second event handler, so it will be the only one (note the unbind method).

```
$("#foobar").unbind("click").click(function() { alert("second"); });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#foobar").click(function () { alert("first"); });
$("#foobar").unbind('click').click(function () { alert("second"); });
```

Notice the [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method. It does exactly what it sounds like.